# PHP : find all occurrences inside pattern and replace each one with different value

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that is like this :

```
Hello my name is [foo], I'm from [foo]
```

Then I declare an array :

```
$foo = array('Sam', 'Tunisia');
```

How can I find all occurence of [foo] in the text and replace the first one with $foo[0], the second with $foo[1] ... The result shoud be like this :

```
 Hello my name is Sam, I'm from Tunisia
```

PS : I have to use the same pattern [foo]

Comment: Take a look at `preg_replace_callback()` and try something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @Rizer123, use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php). For example:

```
<?php

$str = "Hello my name is [foo], I'm from [foo]";
$foo = ['Sam', 'Tunisia'];

// note: passing `$foo` by reference. This allows you to
// unshift entries for each match. If there are more matches
// in `$str` than elements in the `$foo` array, `array_shift()`
// will simply return `null`

echo preg_replace_callback('/\[foo\]/', function() use (&$foo) {
    return array_shift($foo);
}, $str);
```

Yields:

> Hello my name is Sam, I'm from Tunisia

For more reading, see the PHP docs for:

- [Anonymous functions and the `use` language construct](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) (Example #3).
- [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: For fun, here's a ridiculous one-liner that does the same thing: `echo implode('', array_map(function($a, $b) { return $a . $b; }, explode('[foo]', "Hello my name is [foo], I'm from [foo]"), ['Sam', 'Tunisia']));` ;)

Comment: nice idea, but in fact I have more thant one pattern and have to replace them with some data from database, so I have to use preg_replace_callback()

Comment: Of course. I'd never recommend this over the main answer, I'm just having a bit of fun here :)

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use this with case-insensitive ? I tired '/\b[foo\b]/i' but it don't work

Comment: I am not sure why you added the `\b` (word boundary) anchor here, since it's not necessary. More importantly however, you are not escaping the open and close brackets - therefore you have defined your regex with a "character class" of `[foo\b]`. To search for foo surrounded by actual open and close bracket characters you need to escape them - like so: `\[foo\]`. Once you do that, you can add the case-insensitive flag as per your example: `/\[foo\]/i`

Comment: Case-insensitive example here: https://eval.in/482869 - for more on character classes [read here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)